# everytime End phone Call come back to my activity even if i have not make a phone call from my application android

Tags: android, android-intent

i have created application into which user can make a call on button click.

i have found below code which is working fine to make call and come back to my activity when phone call end. but i have one problem in this application that is once i make a phone call from my application and end that phone call, after completing this whole cycle,i have press home button or back button. i will call some one from my phone directory and when end a call it will come back to my application not in phone directory.

```
public void imgbtnCallPhone_Click(View view) {
    EditText txtBusinessPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

        try
        {
           final Intent callIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ txtBusinessPhone.getText()));
           startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
            //Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
        }

}

private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

        String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                            getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

i want a code that will check phone call is related to my application or not, 
if phone call done by my application then after end phone call it will come back 
to my application activity otherwise don't come back to my activity, do it default.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to start your PhoneCallListener right before you call, pass the number you are going to call to the PhoneCallListener and then start the callIntent.

In your PhoneListener, you can check if the number matches with the number you passed from your Activity. If true, restart your activitry, else do nothing.

EDIT:

```
public void imgbtnCallPhone_Click(View view) {
    EditText txtBusinessPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

    // Get your PhoneCallListener and pass the number
    PhoneCallListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    mPhoneListener.yourActivity = true;

    // start listening
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    try
    {
       final Intent callIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ txtBusinessPhone.getText()));
       startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        //Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
    }

}
```

Your PhoneCallListener:

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    public Boolean yourActivity = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling && yourActivity) {

                //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");
                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                yourActivity = false;
                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, so it may contains some errors.

Comment: thanks, please provide example as i am new in android

Comment: problem in this code is that i am unable to find incomingnumber in TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE state. that state gave me empty incomingnumber.

Comment: I think this is because the call is already over. In the edited code I try to save the number when it rings.

Comment: i am not getting incomingnumber in TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING state. it is empty everytime. my main goal is to make a call from phone and when end a call it will back to my activity if phone call from my application.

Comment: I was wrong the whole time, incomingNumber is empty because you are having an outgoing call. Check the new edited code, it uses a Boolean as a flag if your activity did this call.